# Sort a List of Objects by Date

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I have a list of objects that I have retrieved from a webservice call.  On the other end, the list of objects looks like this:

> ({ead=3/11/2016, qty=8}, {ead=4/22/2016, qty=46}, {ead=10/26/2016,
>   qty=34})

However, once the list gets pulled into Salesforce, it comes in this format:

> ({ead=10/26/2016, qty=34}, {ead=3/11/2016, qty=8}, {ead=4/22/2016,
>   qty=46}).

I need to keep the first format.  How do I do this?

Comment: Won't work.  That method doesn't really exist in Salesforce...

Comment: you said you have a **List** of objects, is that a java.utils list???

Answer (score 2):

Since  that is a list of **objects** then you can sort it by the date using [collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<CustomSalesObject> myList = new ArrayList<CustomSalesObject>();
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<CustomSalesObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(CustomSalesObject o1, CustomSalesObject o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
        }
    });
}
```